# SQL Server Browser and Agent don't start

Tags: sql-server

I try to start the server browser and agent but, this don't work. The option "Start" when clicked right click is disabled

I'm using sql server 2017. and the info to start the server and agent does not work

**(I made a mistake, is not a sql express, y sql server and management studio)**

[image]

Comment: The Express version doesn't include SQL Server Agent. Have you looked in your windows event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express does not include SQL Server Agent. Hence it's not possible to create SQL Agent jobs.

as a workaround, you can create sripts as batch files (`sqlcmd -i myBatch.sql`) and use windows Task scheduler to schedule them.